# jquery attaching plugin with .live() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach a jquery `cycle plugin` with `.live()` on `div element`, menas :

currently i am doing :

```
$("div").cycle();
```

but i want to do :

```
$("div").live("which event ?", function() { $(this).cycle(); });
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why are you using [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (which is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and above)? You should probably use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or, in earlier versions of jQuery, [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). Incidentally, what's the context of your question?

Comment: He is most likely trying to attach plugin to elements that don't exist at the time, which has nothing to do with event delegation (and therefore nothing to do with  `.live`). It's a pretty common misunderstanding of what `.live` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to trigger an event automatically? 
If yes, this is the solution:

Apply a custom handler to your element:

```
$("div").live("yourEvent", function() { $(this).cycle(); });
```

Then you can fire this event with the trigger()-function:

```
$("div").trigger("yourEvent");
```

Comment: You can replace this code with `$("div").cycle();`, that is, when you call `$("div").trigger("addCycle")`, you might as well have called `$("div").cycle();`

Comment: Uhmm.. yes but he wanted to know how it works or did i missunderstand something? I don't think so

Comment: How could this be *automatic* if you *manually* call `trigger`

Comment: Why was this accepted? It uses a deprecated method and manual event invocation? This *is not* what the OP's question was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good method of binding to items on a *surprise, I'm here* event. Instead, methods like `.live` (or `.on`, since the former is deprecated) are more useful with mouse and keyboard events (generally speaking).

The best method for automatically applying a plugin to all `div.cycleMe` elements would be to place that logic in the callbak method of the function loading those new elements into the page. For instance, if you had an instance of `$.ajax` that pulled in new data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getSlider",
    success: function( data ) {
        $("#sliders")
            .append(data).find("div.cycleMe:not(.active)")
                .addClass("active").cycle();
    }
});
```

After our slider has been loaded into `#sliders`, our callback function is executed. It finds all `.cycleMe` elements that do not have the `.active` class, adds the class, and then calls the `.cycle()` method against them. The `.active` class here is to ensure we don't call the cycle method again on the *previously-loaded* sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Frst of all, `.live()` is deprecated. It's advised you use `.delegate()` for older jQuery, and `.on()` for versions 1.7+

And if you are loading the plugin to dynamic elements, why not attach them when the elements load?

Example:

```
$.get(url,data,function(html){
    $(html)                  //wrap with jQuery
        .appendTo(somewhere) //add somewhere
        .cycle(html);        //add cycle
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. Calling a jQuery method on an object is not like an event so you cannot do it in the "live" way.